# Keras with data augmentation does (almost) not converge

Tags: machine-learning, keras, data-augmentation

I'm currently playing around with data augmentation in Keras. My model looks as follows:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_2 (InputLayer)         [(None, 1024, 1280, 3)]   0         
_________________________________________________________________
lambda_1 (Lambda)            (None, 128, 128, 3)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 126, 126, 32)      896       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 42, 42, 32)        9248      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 21, 21, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 21, 21, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 14112)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 128)               1806464   
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)          (None, 128)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 6)                 774       
=================================================================
Total params: 1,817,382
Trainable params: 1,817,382
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

The lambda layer basically scales the image.

Training worked ok-ish, however, I do not really have enough data, hence, generalisation was lousy.
Hence, I tried data augmentation.

```
image_gen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rotation_range=20,
        zoom_range=0.15,
        width_shift_range=0.2,
        height_shift_range=0.2,
        shear_range=0.15,
        horizontal_flip=True,
        fill_mode="nearest")
image_gen.fit(x_train, augment=True)
summary = model.fit_generator(image_gen.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size=64), epochs=30, validation_data=(x_valid, y_valid) )
```

But now the fitting is not converging anymore

```
Epoch 1/30
3/3 [==============================] - 37s 12s/step - loss: 6.5018 - categorical_accuracy: 0.6000 - val_loss: 10.0990 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.5217
Epoch 2/30
3/3 [==============================] - 34s 11s/step - loss: 6.5018 - categorical_accuracy: 0.6000 - val_loss: 10.0990 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.5217
Epoch 3/30
3/3 [==============================] - 32s 11s/step - loss: 6.2290 - categorical_accuracy: 0.6000 - val_loss: 7.7606 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.5217
Epoch 4/30
3/3 [==============================] - 36s 12s/step - loss: 6.7746 - categorical_accuracy: 0.6000 - val_loss: 10.0990 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.5217
Epoch 5/30
3/3 [==============================] - 35s 12s/step - loss: 6.7746 - categorical_accuracy: 0.6000 - val_loss: 7.7606 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.5217
Epoch 6/30
3/3 [==============================] - 35s 12s/step - loss: 7.3203 - categorical_accuracy: 0.6000 - val_loss: 10.0990 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.5217
Epoch 7/30
1/3 [=========>....................] - ETA: 4s - loss: 2.6863 - categorical_accuracy: 0.8333
```

I inspected the generated images manually and they look good

Comment: Why is the training accuacy stuck at 0.6?  Is it because the most frequent class appears as 60% of your training data?  (And the model always predicts that particular class.)

Comment: @jkjung13 without da augmentation it converges the ratio is 120:89 with different seeds it Is stuck at other values

Comment: It seems the model is stuck at some dead zone and cannot learn.  I'd suggest you to try different initializations of the network, especially in the last Dense layer.  For example, try to initialize it with a small positive "bias" value.

Comment: Reference: https://keras.io/layers/core/, https://keras.io/initializers/.  I suggest you to try a Constant bias_initializer with value, say, 0.01.